Write RTSP stream using opencv-python
I want to read individual frames from an RTSP source, manipulate them and then put them back into an RTSP stream. For the beginning, I started with a simple example.
Reading the frames from the rtsp source via opencv cv2.VideoCapture() works fine.
But I cannot get the cv2.VideoWriter to initialise correctly.
Here is my code:
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://ip:port/source', cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

frame_width = int(capture.get(3))
frame_height = int(capture.get(4))
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

output_stream = cv2.VideoWriter('rtsp://ip:port/my_output', cv2.CAP_FFMPEG, codec, 30, 
                               (frame_width, frame_height)) 
if not output_stream.isOpened():
  raise Exception("can't open VideoWriter!")
                 
while capture.isOpened():
  (status, frame) = capture.read()
  if status:
    #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    output_stream.write(frame)

It throws an exception when I check if the output_stream isOpen otherwise no error message appears:
[h264 @ 0000016a37a9ea00] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0000016a37a9ea00] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0000016a37a9ea00] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0000016a37a9ea00] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0000016a37a9ea00] Missing reference picture, default is 0
[h264 @ 0000016a37a9ea00] decode_slice_header error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\test_rtsp_stream_opencv.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception("can't open VideoWriter!")
Exception: can't open VideoWriter!

There are several posts on this topic but I haven't got any further.
If I define a file like "output_video.avi' as the output, the whole thing works
My Python version is 3.10.11 and opencv-python is 4.9.0.80
Thanks in advance!
